# Dynamically instantiating/pausing Youtube video (iFrame API) on hover exit of parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, instantiation

I am working on a prototype for a mega menu type navigation bar. The way that it functions is someone rolls over a main menu item, and the large drop down section appears.

I also want to include the ability to have embedded Youtube videos in the drop down sections. My problem with this, is when a drop down section that contains a video is exited, the video will continue to play in the background.

**My issue that I'm running into is I cannot seem to figure out how to dynamically instantiate, get, and pause the videos in an open drop down.**

I've read through the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de#Getting_Started) and I've seen the manual instantiation of  the `YT.Player` objects, but I would ideally want to do this dynamically and be able to pause a given `YT.Player` instance.

I **DO NOT** want to just remove the source of the iFrame and reassign it back to the iFrame. This just creates more HTTP requests.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/SZzde/) so far. And my code:

**The HTML:**

```
<ul id="mainNav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <div class="left">
                <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
                <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 4</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 5</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, nesciunt, doloremque ratione officia voluptate placeat recusandae totam libero explicabo magnam labore a delectus commodi dolor iusto quae atque ipsum aliquid!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><iframe id="trainingYTVideo" class="youtubeVideo" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3f7l-Z4NF70?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#mainNav{width: 960px; position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#mainNav > li { float: left; width:120px; padding:0 20px; height:30px; background: #ccc; list-style: none;}
#mainNav > li:nth-child(2n) {background: #ddd;}
#mainNav > li:hover{background: #eee;}
#mainNav .secondaryNav{ display: none; position:absolute; width: 940px; left:0; top: 30px; background:#eee; padding: 10px;}
.subnavFeature{float: left; padding: 10px;}
.left{float: left;}
```

**The JS:**

```
// jQuery 1.9.1
$(function(){
    $('#mainNav > li').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.secondaryNav').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).find('.secondaryNav').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200, function(){
                    var videos = $(this).find('.youtubeVideo');
                    if( videos.length > 0 ){
                        // pause each video
                    }
                });
            }
        );
});
```

**TL;DR:** How do I dynamically instantiate, get, and pause the videos in an open drop down?

Comment: Any reasoning for the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

**JS**

```
var youtubeVideo1,
    youtubeVideo2,
    youtubeVideo3,
    youtubeVideos;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    youtubeVideo1 = new YT.Player('youtubeVideo1');
    youtubeVideo2 = new YT.Player('youtubeVideo2');
    youtubeVideo3 = new YT.Player('youtubeVideo3');
    youtubeVideos = [youtubeVideo1, youtubeVideo2, youtubeVideo3];
}
$(function () {    

    $('#mainNav > li').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.secondaryNav').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
        },

        function () {
            $(this).find('.secondaryNav').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200, function () {
            // var youtubeVideos = $(this).find('.youtubeVideo');
            if (youtubeVideos.length > 0) {
                $.each(youtubeVideos, function(){
                    this.pauseVideo();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mainNav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <div class="left">
                <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
                <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><iframe id="youtubeVideo1" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sERJZ5KJHz0?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 4</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 5</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><img width="200" src="http://www.designcrowd.com/img/blog/google.png"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, nesciunt, doloremque ratione officia voluptate placeat recusandae totam libero explicabo magnam labore a delectus commodi dolor iusto quae atque ipsum aliquid!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><iframe id="youtubeVideo2" class="youtubeVideo" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3f7l-Z4NF70?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, molestiae vel consequuntur tempora optio aut saepe eum perferendis. Atque, debitis, veniam iste vero voluptatibus amet omnis ducimus commodi labore reiciendis.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nav</a>
        <div class="secondaryNav">
            <div class="subnavFeature"><iframe id="youtubeVideo3" class="youtubeVideo"  width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RmMojHCPMJ4?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            <p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm counting on not having more than 6 videos in this navigation bar at any given time.

Answer (score -1):

You do not use youtube js api in the right way. To make your job easy i recommend to you to include this [small plugin](https://github.com/iamntz/youtubeEmbed/blob/master/ntzYoutubeEmbed.js) and then you will load your videos like :

```
<div class="youtubeVideo" data-youtube-id="3f7l-Z4NF70"></div>
```

That if from your fiddle will look like :

```
if( videos.length > 0 ) {
  $('.youtubeVideo', this).trigger('player-stop');
}
```

**Note:** You do not need to load something else from youtube. Everything is done here, you just have to call it like `$('.youtubeVideo').ntzYoutubeEmbed();`

Comment: This does not answer my question, but merely suggests setting up a different way, and with different markup, no less. Also, 'You do not use youtube js api in the right way.' is very vague.